# Showing a curve must lie on a sphere.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, spherical-geometry

> Let $\mathbf{r}(t)$ be a parametrisation of a curve $\mathcal{C}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\mathbf{r}(0) = (R, −R, R)$, where $R \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $\mathbf{r}(t)\neq \mathbf{0}$ and $\mathbf{r}(t)\cdot\mathbf{r'}(t) = 0$ for all points of $\mathcal{C}$. Show that any such $\mathcal{C}$ must lie on the surface of a sphere. Find the position of the sphere’s centre and determine its radius.

I've tried integrating giving,
$$
\int \mathbf{r}(t)\cdot\mathbf{r'}(t)\text{dt} = \frac{\mathbf{r}(t)^2}{2} \\
\implies t_0 = \frac{\mathbf{r}(t)^2}{2}
$$
where $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ but I don't see how this helps. Also differentiating $||\mathbf{r}(t)-s_0||^2$ where $s_0$ is the centre of our sphere $\mathcal{S}$ should equal zero as its a constant radius but I don't see how that helps.

Comment: If the inner product $<r(t),r'(t)>=0$, then $<r(t),r(t)>=constant$.

Comment: Yeah that's what I get from integrating, but what does it mean if the dot product is constant?

Comment: If the dot product is constant then the vector components satisfy an identity of the form $x^2+y^2+z^2=c$.

Comment: Ah okay we haven't covered that yet so I'll look for a proof online. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty much what you said. Let $f(t) = \mathbf{r}(t)^2 \equiv \langle \mathbf{r}(t), \mathbf{r}(t)\rangle$. Then, differentiating the function $f$ yields:
\begin{align}
f'(t) &= \mathbf{r}(t) \cdot \mathbf{r}'(t) \\
&= 0 \tag{by hypothesis}
\end{align}
Since $f'$ is identically zero, it follows that $f$ is identically equal to a constant. In other words, for all $t \in \Bbb{R}$, we must have that
\begin{align}
f(t) &= f(0) \\
&= \mathbf{r}(0) \cdot \mathbf{r}(0) \\
&= (R,-R,R) \cdot (R,-R,R) \\
&= 3R^2
\end{align}
Now, recall that $f(t) = \mathbf{r}(t) \cdot \mathbf{r}(t) = x(t)^2 + y(t)^2 + z(t)^2$ is the squared length of the position vector $\mathbf{r}(t)$. This squared length being constant for all time $t$ means that the curve lies on some sphere. In particular, it lies on the sphere centered at the origin, having radius $\sqrt{3} |R|.$

---

What you did by integration is also equivalent to what I wrote. To figure out what the constant $t_0$ must be, note that if you evaluate both sides at $t=0$ then you find that $t_0 = \dfrac{3R^2}{2}$.